# Write from text file to decision tree

Tags: java, io, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a decision tree from a text file.

```
public static BTNode<String> fileToTree (String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    BTNode<String> node = new BTNode("", null, null);
    BTNode<String> answer = fileToTreeHelper(node, file);
    file.close();
    return answer;
}
   public static BTNode<String> fileToTreeHelper (BTNode<String> node, Scanner fileScanner) throws IOException {
    String line;

    if(node == null){
            node = new BTNode<String>(fileScanner.nextLine(), null, null);
            fileToTreeHelper(node, fileScanner);
    }else{
        if(fileScanner.hasNext()){
                if(node.isLeaf()){
                    node.setData(fileScanner.nextLine());
                }
                if(node.getLeft() == null) {
                    line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                        if(line.contains("?")) {
                            node.setLeft(new BTNode<String>(line, null, null));
                        }
                        if(line.contains(";")) {
                             node.setLeft(new BTNode<>(line,null, null));
                             node.setRight(new BTNode<>(fileScanner.nextLine(),null, null));
                        }
                    }

                if(node.getRight() == null) {
                    line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                    if(line.contains("?")) {
                        node.setRight(new BTNode<String>(line, null, null));
                    }
                    if(line.contains(";")) {
                         node.getLeft().setLeft(new BTNode<>(line,null, null));
                         node.getLeft().setRight(new BTNode<>(fileScanner.nextLine(),null, null));
                         node.setRight(new BTNode<String>(line, null, null));
                         fileToTreeHelper(node.getRight(), fileScanner);
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    return node;
}
```

This is what I have so far; when I run it the decision tree should look something like this:

```
Are you a mammal?
   Are you bigger than a cat?
      Kangaroo;
      Mouse;
   Do you live underwater?
      Trout;
      Robin;
```

But so far all I am getting is this:

```
Are you a mammal?
    Are you bigger than a cat?
        Kangaroo;
        --
    --
```

Any help on how to do this? I know I need to recursively call this function but this is not working quite well. Any ideas?

Comment: How does your node look like what are the 3 constructors for. Also i take it each question can lead to only 2 answers or questions?

Comment: @Ludjer Yes each question can only have two answers. The constructors are for creating a node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your algorithm is confusing, it should be something like this:

```
    Node node = new Node(fileScanner.nextLine())
    // If the node is a question, it should have 2 subnodes with the answers / nested questions.
    if(line.contains("?")){
        node.setLeft(fileToTreeHelper(...));
        // If there is an option that has only 1 answer, then this should have an if that
        // checks if there is a ";" and then create the node or set it as null.
        node.setRight(fileToTreeHelper(...));
    }
    // If it is not a question, then it's just an answer to a previous question and returns.
    return node;
```

Comment: How do I recursively call the fileToTreeHelper? I've updated it. It works fine with the small inputs

Comment: in the context it would be fileToTreeHelper(node, fileScanner)

Comment: Design tip: Check that in my algorithm the node is created before the if(), as it should be created with the same parameters in both cases (and your answer shows it does, so you should get it out of the if). It is bad design to have an if() statement that repeats the same actions in the if and in the else (in case you choose to change the declaration, you will have to change 2 different places and may result in bugs)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. Thanks. Works perfectly now.

```
public static BTNode<String> fileToTree (String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        BTNode<String> node = null;
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner (file);
        BTNode<String> answer = fileToTreeHelper(fileScanner);
        return answer;
    }

   public static BTNode<String> fileToTreeHelper (Scanner fileScanner) throws IOException {
           BTNode node = null;
           String line = fileScanner.nextLine();

           if(line.contains("?")){
               node = new BTNode<String>(line, null, null);
               node.setLeft(fileToTreeHelper(fileScanner));
               node.setRight(fileToTreeHelper(fileScanner)); 

           }else{
               node = new BTNode<String>(line, null, null);
               return node;

           }
           return node;
    }
```